# How «Wait until application launch» applescript?

Tags: applescript, automator

How to write the code correctly?

I run the application Photoshop in the automator
I'm waiting for it to fully load
Then I press 10 times Tab and press Enter.

I've tried that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yH8h.png)

Looks like that part doesn't work. Because Tab starts to click before the application is fully loaded. What's wrong? Thanks!

```
repeat until application launch
delay 0.5 end repeat delay 0.5
```

Comment: 1. The **Launch Application** _action_ does not return anything, so the `repeat until application launch` in the ensuing **Run AppleScript** _action_ does nothing! 2. I see no programatic need to use three **Run AppleScript** _actions_ as you have. A properly written _script_ in one **Run AppleScript** _action_ should be all that's necessary.  3. Without knowing the name of the _application_ being launched it's impossible to give explicit advice, however, using, e.g., **System Events** you'll probably have to check for the existence of a **UI element** that's only available once fully loaded.

Comment: user3439894, thanks for your answer. Application is Photoshop. I want to create new doc. Also it can be trello app.

Comment: RE: "Application is Photoshop. I want to create new doc. Also it can be trello app" --  I do not have **Photoshop**, however, I would think something like `tell application "Photoshop" to make new document` would make a new document. Also, when you are going to programmatically press the **tab** _key_ many times, you need to have a `delay` between them. I also do not have **Trello**, so I can't be of any explicit help, sorry.

Comment: The main question based on your answer is how to return anything to automator? What data must be provided to the automator so that it understands that the application has loaded and can proceed to the next step.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**This is the answer:**

```
tell application "Your app"
    launch
    activate
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the OP does not understand the main thing: **GUI scripting** (in this case, sending **10 tabs**, and then **Enter**, that is, **keystroke tab** and **keystroke return** in AppleScript language) **only works with the frontmost window**. And the **launch** command launches an application without bringing its window to the front.

The correct approach is 1) use the **activate** application "Photoshop" command 2) use the **make new document** command, 3) check if the new window exists, 4) send keystroke commands. In the Automator, the **Run AppleScript action** should be something like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Photoshop"
        activate
        make new document with properties {name:"myNewDocument"}
        repeat until window "myNewDocument" exists
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat 10 times
            delay 0.1
            keystroke tab
        end repeat
        keystroke return
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

NOTE: not tested, because PhotoShop.app is not installed on my Mac. I am ready to correct my script, if needed. In general, the question is not quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Photoshop, but I know that it has a loading screen. I tried the following code in [Affinity Photo](https://affinity.serif.com/) which is a similar product to Photoshop.

```applescript
tell application "Photoshop"
    launch
    set theBool to false
    repeat until theBool
        tell application "System Events" to ¬
            if menu item "Close" of ¬
                menu 1 of ¬
                menu bar item "File" of ¬
                menu bar 1 of ¬
                application process "Photoshop" exists then ¬
                set theBool to true
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
end tell
```

The `repeat until theBool` checks if the loading screen is over by checking if some menu item exists which isn't available when the loading screen is open. If the `"Close"` and the `"File"` don't work in Photoshop, you may choose something else.

Comment: @user3439894 I now removed the `repeat until it is running`. It was originally added because Affinity Photo, the image editor I use, needs about 20 seconds before it first launches. Since then I‘ve implemented the check for the menu item which makes the `repeat until it is running`-check obsolete.

Comment: gurkensaas, As mentioned in a now deleted previous comment, I've added an appropriate `delay` within the `repeat until theBool` _loop_ to limit the amount of polling it does. Also, in the _code block_ I changed `applescript` to `lang-applescript` so it would actually show as **AppleScript** _code_.